# How to use Bool with [DataContract]?

Tags: c#, console-application, datacontract

I recently started using [DataContract] to add a save feature to my text-adventure game, i made a Player class with [DataContract] that contains its stats, correct HP, etc.

I think DataContract is a much better way to save progress then just a XML file, so i want to use [DataContract] to save my game's options. so i made an Options class, but until now ive used only Strings and numbers with my [DataContract]. 
i know that after the IDE compiles the DataContract to Json, or XML, both of them are just text files. so im not sure how does the Bool represents in the text file, or how to create a [DataMember] Bool.

Comment: It's simple, add the `DataMemberAttribute` tag to the boolean property.

Comment: Use the data-type bool (all lowercase) with the [DataMember] attribute and it will be serialized/deserialized properly...